# Как установить максимально и минимальное значение для Input type number React/JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

Дело в том что в теге number я указал значения для min и для max. Если изменять число стрелками, то все ок , но если вводить число с клавиатуры, то можно свободно ввести число меньше минимального значения и больше максимального.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="LVL" className="text-area-minimal" min="0" max="999"></input>
```

Comment: Вообще в React, насколько я знаю, по-хорошему на UI не должно быть данных, которых нет в state. То есть UI всегда берёт значение только и только из state. И если вы сделаете так, то всё будет очень просто: если пользователь вводит значение меньше 0 или больше 999, то такое число в state не записывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не поленюсь то добавлю и второй вариант.

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-butterfly-8riee?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  const setNumber = ({ target }) => {
    let { value, min, max } = target;
    value = Math.max(Number(min), Math.min(Number(max), Number(value)));

    setVal(value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" onChange={setNumber} value={val} min="0" max="10" />
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, только есть нюанс с отрицательными значениями. Если поставить `min < 0` то отрицательное значение можно ввести с клавиатуры только предварительно набрав положительное (например "10"), а потом поставив перед ним минус, что для пользователя будет не очень очевидно.
И лучше бы `setNumber` обернуть в `useCallback`.

Comment: @ArtyomKozhemiakin Вы предлагаете другой ответ или же указываете в каком случае будет баг в коде? И не нужно тут использовать `useCallback`. Это лишнее, во вторых в вопросе нет никакой  речи про перформанс и оптимизацию.

Comment: Указываю на проблемный момент. У нас есть похожий кейс, мы это решаем двойным стейтом (один как текстовое представление, второй числовое), текстовое сбрасывается в числовое каждый раз когда текстовое полностью соответствует числовому + при снятии фокуса. Я могу сбросить, но это довольно сложная реализация с множеством подводных камней.

`useCallback` тут будет не лишним, потому что ваш `setNumber` никогда не пересоздается, это просто best practice. Лучше начать использовать useCallback и useMemo в нужных местах до того как возникнут проблемы с производительностью, а не после :)

Comment: @ArtyomKozhemiakin в вопросе не был ничего про обработку минусового кейса.И если так говорите то, покажите свой вариант. Мне просто лень  дополнительно потратить время и дополнить ответ который не нужен человеку задавший вопрос.Best practice-om считается использовать `useCallback` везде, где это возможно? Хотел бы посмотреть на проект над которым вы работаете. Наверное вы даже простые логи оборачиваете под `usecallback` :) Оптимизацию надо делать в последней очередь.